# After building image with docker-compose build image changes are not reflecting

Tags: docker, docker-compose, node-modules

when i am running auth-ui with docker-compose run --sevice-ports auth-ui. all the changes which i have made in auth-ui reflecting properly, so i am building new docker image after change in code,

this is my docker-compose.yml file of auth-ui.

```
version: "2"
services:
  auth-ui:
    image: openlmis/dev-ui:9.0.2-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9876:9876"
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    env_file: .env
    volumes_from:
      - ui-components
    depends_on:
      - ui-components
  ui-components:
    image: openlmis/ui-components:7.2.4-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
      - '/openlmis-ui-components'
  image:
    build: .
    image: openlmis/auth-ui
```

it gets created as openlmis/auth-ui:latest.

then i configure that image in reference-ui's docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  reference-ui:
    image: openlmis/dev-ui:9.0.2-SNAPSHOT
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9876:9876"
    env_file: .env
    volumes_from:
      - auth-ui
      - fulfillment-ui
      - referencedata-ui
      - requisition-ui
      - report-ui
      - stockmanagement-ui
      - cce-ui
      - ui-components
      - ui-layout
    depends_on:
      - auth-ui
      - fulfillment-ui
      - referencedata-ui
      - requisition-ui
      - report-ui
      - stockmanagement-ui
      - cce-ui
      - ui-components
      - ui-layout
  auth-ui:
    image: openlmis/auth-ui:latest
    volumes:
      - '/openlmis-auth-ui'
  fulfillment-ui:
    image: openlmis/fulfillment-ui:6.0.8-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
      - '/openlmis-fulfillment-ui'
  referencedata-ui:
    image: openlmis/referencedata-ui:5.6.4-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
      - '/openlmis-referencedata-ui'
  report-ui:
    image: openlmis/report-ui:5.2.5-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
      - '/openlmis-report-ui'
  requisition-ui:
    image: openlmis/requisition-ui:7.0.4-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
      - '/openlmis-requisition-ui'
  stockmanagement-ui:
    image: openlmis/stockmanagement-ui:2.0.8-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
     - '/openlmis-stockmanagement-ui'
  cce-ui:
    image: openlmis/cce-ui:1.0.8-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
     - '/openlmis-cce-ui'
  ui-components:
    image: openlmis/ui-components:7.2.4-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
      - '/openlmis-ui-components'
  ui-layout:
    image: openlmis/ui-layout:5.1.8-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
      - '/openlmis-ui-layout'
  image:
    build: .
    image: openlmis/reference-ui
```

but the changes which i made is not reflecting when i try to run reference ui with docker-compose run --service-ports reference-ui.

am i missing something ?

Comment: What are all of those `volumes:` and `volumes_from:` blocks supposed to do?  Are you trying to use volumes to share code between containers, and then they're not getting updated when you rebuild?

Comment: yes @David, also i have updated reference-ui's docker-compose.yml.

Comment: If you're expecting the volume content to be updated, Docker won't overwrite the user data in the volumes with updated content from images.  Can you put all of the dependencies in the `dev-ui` image's Dockerfile, so that you can run the container without any volume declarations at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you rebuild the image, you will need to remove the container from the other docker compose stack to start a new container with the new image. Try `docker-compose rm -sf auth-ui` and then retry your run command.

Comment: thanks @wobr for the suggestion, actually what i have done is i have made some ui related  changes in login page of auth ui service, changes are not reflecting after adding latest image of auth-ui in reference-ui's docker-compose.yml file, after [ docker-compose rm -sf auth-ui ] login page in not loading at all.

Comment: Did you do `docker-compose up -d` after `docker-compose rm -sf auth-ui`?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) states `docker-compose run` runs a one off command against a service, which is not what you want to do.

What you want to do is to use the first `docker-compose.yml` to build the image and the second one to use it to create a container.

So in the directory containing the first `docker-compose.yml` (the one you call `docker-compose.yml file of auth-ui`) you should run `docker-compose build` to build the image and in the directory with the second `docker-compose.yml` (the one you call `reference-ui's docker-compose.yml`) you should run `docker-compose up -d` to update your servie with the new image (assuming you want to run the services in the background, otherwise skip `-d`).

Documentation for `docker-compose build` can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/) and for `docker-compose up` [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).